# Anchor tags in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, controller, anchor

My codebase is built in Cakephp. 
I have an update button which processes a "notes" field. I have a working controller update/write that redirects back to the page, so the "hard" bit is done...

However: from a usability point of view, this redirects to the raw URL, and hence to the top of the page every time.
The `<input>` field has an id, so I simply want to link back to it using an anchor tag.

Here's what works [controller]:

```
$this->redirect('/review/index/'.item->getEmployeeId());
```

I tried to add in the following:

```
$this->redirect('/review/index/'.$item->getEmployeeId().'#'.$item->getEmployeeId());
```

However - this seems to be stripped out... The write still works, but the anchor is stripped out.

For debugging/quick gotchas: I have tested the raw URL out and it redirects to the `<input>`.

Is there another way to do this? I'm assuming this is some cakephp "magic" and I simply don't know how to apend an anchor. Some google searches and poking in the API don't seem to clear things up though.

Many thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend using the "recommended" way of generating urls: using arrays. This way (as documented) your urls will be cleaner and future proof, especially regarding routing. As for your issue, that will most likely also be solved as the hash is then not encoded.

Comment: `this seems to be stripped out` - what does that mean (be specific)?

Comment: "this seems to be stripped out" <-- by this I mean:
If I use this redirect, the url functions as expected UP UNTIL the #. 
From the # and onwards, this is stripped off/truncated ... whatever term you chose to call it. 
The redirect thus goes to the correct page, but with no anchor tag.

Comment: That's [simply not true](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/6038914) - which means something else is responsible/interfering or the problem isn't as described.

Comment: Hi all.
The above didn't help, the hash element is still removed within my code.
After some more looking at things over a few days I've found a different approach to fix this UI problem (going to do an AJAX write). 
Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 2):

Following: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::redirect

Use this:

```
$url = array(
    'controller' => 'review',
    'action' => 'index',
    $item->getEmployeeId(),
    '#' => $item->getEmployeeId()
);
$this->redirect($url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've changed the link to the code as above, but unfortunately, the # item is still being ignored.

Comment: You must be doing sth wrong. I just checked with my app. Redirects with hashes work for me this way.. Any special htaccess setting?